# Facebook share button - JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add facebook share button on my website, that should just post some  content on the wall. who want to share it.I used this code to do that.
but i want to share image and some description with link.
how encode url for this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Your title" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Your description" />
<script>
function share() {
    var width = 626;
    var height = 436;
    var yourPageToShare = location.href;
    var sharerUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(yourPageToShare);
    var l = window.screenX + (window.outerWidth - width) / 2;
    var t = window.screenY + (window.outerHeight - height) / 2;
    var winProps = ['width='+width,'height='+height,'left='+l,'top='+t,'status=no','resizable=yes','toolbar=no','menubar=no','scrollbars=yes'].join(',');
    var win = window.open(sharerUrl, 'fbShareWin', winProps);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" value="Share" onclick="share();">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is much better to cunsult [FB Developers API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) There are some features could generate the proper code automatically.

If you like it could even automatically show how many people already shared this.